# Как отправить данные из формы в Телеграм и/или на почту?

Tags: html5

Здраствуйте, в вопросе всё сказано но хочу добавить я кучу роликов посмотрел прочитал много статей но ни одна не отправила данные из формы в Телеграм, так что кроме подсказки как сделать скрипт на php и/или js можете ещё попытаться разжевать то куда тыкать вставлять и т.д. буду очень благодарен! Вот стандартная разметка:

```
             <div class="form">
                 <div class="book_form">
                 <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваш ник" required>
                    <input type="text" name="book_name" placeholder="Имя книги" required>
                    <input type="text" name="avtor_name" placeholder="Имя автора" required>
                    <textarea type="text" name="otziv" placeholder="Ваш отзыв о книге"></textarea>                        
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="sovet_form">
                    <h2>Что вы предлагаете нам улучшить на сайте?</h2>
                    <textarea type="text" name="sovet" placeholder="Ваши предложения"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="send-button">Отправить</button>
                </form>
             </div>
```

Comment: Если в первую форму добавить кнопку, то она и сама отправится по указанному адресу при нажатии

Comment: @SwaD Значит можно без всей этой мутни с php и js? Значит можно просто добавить ссылку и оно автоматически будет отправит сообщение в Телеграм? Просто сколько я не гуглил оно мне выдавало что-то по типу "Как отправлять текст с помощью PHP" или "Как сделать бота на php который будет отправлять текст из html формы". Можете подсказать и рассказать как это сделать?

Comment: Нет, придется повозится, как минимум с серверной частью, т.к. кто то должен же принимать данные, обрабатывать... Не совсем понятно, при чем здесь телеграмм, ну да и ладно. При нажатии на кнопку, содержимое всех input удет по адресу, указанному в action тега form. Другое дело, если перед отправкой вы хотите их провалидировать, например, тут нужен JS.

Comment: Так что берите в руки учабник по PHP и javaScript и дерзайте. Не будет что то получаться, приходите с кодом и ошибкой, поможем, чем сможем. Просто помните, между помочь и сделать за вас, большая разница )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в форму кнопку. Например `<button type="submit">Отправить</button>`

При нажатии на кнопку данные формы будут отправлены на скрипт `assets/php/telegram.php`. Конечно нужно чтобы он уже был написан.

Отправку данных в телеграм или на почту нужно запрограммировать в этом скрипте. Данные полей формы будут доступны в нем через массив $_POST.

Документация телеграм [тут](https://core.telegram.org/api). Отправить письмо из PHP можно при помощи функции [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php).